# Filter datagridview with text box VB

Tags: vb.net, forms, events, datagridview, textbox

I've created a form that contains a datagridview and I've attached a datasource, works well if I want to see every record but I only want it to show a certain persons view, I found some code that people claim works but when I run the program I get an syntax error...

Syntax error: Missing operand after 'number' operator.

SO has helped me a lot in the past since I'm new to programming, and if I may ask can you guys help me one again?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _ 
                                  Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.TextLength > 0 Then
        frmReportMenu.ProjectBindingSource.Filter = _ 
                String.Format("Register number Like '%" & TextBox1.Text) & "%'"
    Else
        frmReportMenu.ProjectBindingSource.Filter = String.Empty
    End If
End Sub
```

I've created a button when the user clicks on the button a form appears with a textbox

Comment: If `Register number` is a column, how can that be with a space? shouldn't it be like `[Register number]`?

Comment: BTW: This is exactly why I never allow spaces in column names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the column name is what is giving you the error. As per my comment,

It shouldn't contain a space between `Register` and `Number`. If it has a space then you have to wrapt the column name like this: `[Register number]`

Try this please: 
`String.Format("[Register number] Like '%" & TextBox1.Text) & "%'"`

Comment: `:D` it's not stupid, sometimes it does happen... Happy coding :)

Comment: It is amazing how many times those AHA! moments happen. As a contact at a company who I was installing some code said when I finally figured out the final problem I was having "Dawns the light over Marble Head." (Marble Head is in New Hampshire)

Answer (score 0):

The right parenthesis should be here: `String.Format("Register number Like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'")`

Not here: `String.Format("Register number Like '%" & TextBox1.Text) & "%'"`